# show ip bgp 192.168.101.0 bestpath はどのような結果になりますか？

Tags: python

展示した画像を参照してください。このPythonコードでどのような結果が得られますか?

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

> A. showコマンドの出力をフォーマットせずに表示します
> B. showコマンドの出力をフォーマットされた方法で表示します
> C. Telnetを使用してCiscoデバイスに接続し、ルーティングテーブル情報をエクスポートします
> D. SSHを使用してCiscoデバイスに接続し、ルーティングテーブル情報をエクスポートします

すみませんこちらの問題がわからないのですが、出力結果は、Dになりますか？
私は、Dを選択しました。

参考サイトはこちらになります。

※解答文が若干違うところがあります。

https://www.exam4training.com/which-outcome-is-achieved-with-this-python-code/?_gl=1*w1qiwv*_ga*VGY3bTZESjQxU1RsTnBoY2xVdXQxdjNXaDdoLXF2MkRLbWVjdjJwazJqUkc5b3VRekdqT1B0VXNrRmZrc3Biag..#respond

他の人からは、Bが正解と言われたのですが、Bが正解になる理由も合わせて教えて頂きたいです。すみませんご迷惑をおかけしてしまいますが、何卒よろしくお願いいたします。

※追記になります。
@nekketsuuuさん
Dだと思った理由は、画像の1行目で
client.connect (ip, port=22,username=usr,password=pswd)
ポート22を指定しているからです。
このように解釈して、Dを選択しました。
よろしくお願いします。

@ cubick♦さん
わかりました。
実際自分でPythonインストールして検証してみます。

@ keitaro_soさん
回答者様に、Bになる理由を聞いたのですが、回答が返ってきていないです。
解説自体は、されて貰えなかったので、私自身まだモヤモヤしている状態です。
納得は、まだできていないです。

Comment: なぜ D だと思われましたか？　適切な回答をするために、質問者さんが D だと考えた思考過程を知りたいです。間違っていても構いませんので、どのように解釈して D だと結論なさったのかを [edit] して追記いただけませんでしょうか。

Comment: コードの実行結果がどうなるかは、実際に手元で実行してみることが一番理解を進めるための近道だと思います。

Comment: おそらく質問するべきは「Bと答えた方他の人」に対して質問するべきかなと思います。参考サイトの「VIEW ANSWER]を見るとDですし、その人が解説が納得いかないものだったらその人に追加質問するべきで、その人の解説が納得いくものだったらその納得した内容をこの質問分に追記してみてください。

Answer (score 1):

D が正解ですね。

Cisco の show コマンドは何ぞやとか BGP テーブルとは、などどいう以前に、

22 番ポートに connect しているので SSH の唯一の選択肢は D だけです。

Comment: +1: 本当に正確には `client` の定義の部分までないと挙動を考えられませんが、常識的に考えるならこの回答のような挙動を期待するようなコードになっています。